# some explanation needed about $this in php?

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am a little confused about something:

I am working on a php project using OOP.

I have a class with a constructor in it like this:

```
public function __construct(){
    include("myconn.php");
    $myconnect = new connect();
    $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='. $myconnect->db, $myconnect->user, $myconnect->pass);
    $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
 }
```

I didn't put `private $conn;` before the class constructor and I was able to use the variable `conn` in my methods like this: `$q = $this->conn->query($sql) or die("failed!");`

After noticing that in the example I am following there is a `private $conn;` I was confused why wasn't an error popped up.

Can someone please explain this? and also a little explanation about $this scope will be great.

Comment: [PHP: The Basics](http://au2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: Look at the docs about [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). `$this` refers to the current object in non-static methods.

Comment: Side note: use `include_once()` instead of `include()`.

Comment: @HamZa does include works for both including classes and including sections (menu, header, footer...)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you don't define a class property but assign a value to it the first time, it is added to the object as a public property.  By setting it explicitly private you lose access to it outside of the object.

```
Class A {
   public function __construct() {
       $this->foo = 'Hi';
   }
}

$a = new A();
echo $a->foo; // Outputs 'Hi';

Class B {
   private $bar;
   public function __construct() {
       $this->bar = 'Howdy';   // Accessible only to instances of B
   }
}

$b = new B();
echo $b->bar;  // Error accessing a private property
```

This also applies outside any class definition:

```
$object = new \stdClass();
$object->property = 'abc';    // Automatically public
echo $object->property;       // Outputs 'abc'
```

Casting an array to an object also creates public properties automatically:

```
$object = (object) [
    'property' => 'abc'
];
echo $object->property;       // Outputs 'abc'
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer, another question: include works for both including classes and including sections (menu, header, footer...)?

Comment: Include just runs another script at the point it's included. Whatever is in the script executes - class defs, HTML output, echo statements, whatever.